# I cannot open any port on my GCP instance. I'm trying to open port 25565

Tags: google-cloud-platform, ubuntu-16.04, portforwarding

For whatever reason, I cannot open any ports on my Instance. Before I add a firewall rule trying to open 25565, I used https://www.yougetsignal.com/tools/open-ports/ and it had taken a few seconds to check. Now, when I added the firewall rule, it immediately says the port is closed. [GCP Firewall Rules Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gZWEr.png)
I then tried running `netstat -an | grep "LISTEN "`, and the output was

`tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:27017         0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN`

Then, I tried deleting the firewall rules I made and tried adding through the GCP command line.
My output there was
`Creating firewall...done.
NAME       NETWORK  DIRECTION  PRIORITY  ALLOW      DENY  DISABLED
minecraft  default  INGRESS    1000      tcp:25565        False`
I then tried running `netstat -an | grep "LISTEN "` again, and my output was the same. Any help would be greatly appreciated. I am running Ubuntu 16.04 on a custom 1vCPU 4.75gb ram setup.

Comment: Google Cloud Firewall rules do not open ports within your instance, they just allow traffic on the specifies ports thru the firewall to your instance. Do you have an application running that is listening on port 25565. Your `netstat` output indicates NO. The only item listening on an external interface is `ssh`.

Comment: @JohnHanley yes, I do now. My netstat  output is

`tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:27017         0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN
tcp6       0      0 :::25565                :::*                    LISTEN` however I still cannot connect.

Comment: I do not see anything in you output listening for TCP (IPv4) port 25565. I do see something listening for TCP6 (IPv6). You are most likely trying to connect using the standard IPv4 but nobody is listening on that protocol.

Comment: @JohnHanley I've changed my settings to make it IPv4 port 25565, yet i still cannot connect. My netstat output is 

`tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:27017         0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN

tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN

tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:25565           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN

tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN`

Answer (score 0):

I highly suspect that the port 25565 is already being used by another process. For this reason, you are unable to connect to it.

Try the following troubleshooting steps.

Type:

- $ netstat -tulpn

This command will show a list of all processes running on their respective ports. If the port 25565 is there, take a look at the existing process running on it. You may then kill that process.

For more information on troubleshooting the processes running on port 25565, you may consult [this article](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/what-process-has-open-linux-port/).